# Going through a list to get similar elements and indexes

Tags: c#, performance, c#-4.0, logic

I have a List myList = new List() { 8 ,5 ,**3** ,3 ,3, 3, 3 ,**3** ,4 ,5 ,3 ,8 };

Let's say I select the 5th element of my list which is a 3.

I want to find the start and end indexes of the similar values of the given element as long as it is similar

So, I need the index of the first 3 (in this case 2)  and the last 3 (in this case 7).

For this, I decided to use a while loop to go the the start of the list  and another while loop to go to the end of list.

But it feels like a costly/slow way of achieving the desired result.

Do you know of a faster/better way of doing this ?

Thanks !

Comment: if you select second element (5) what should be the correct result ?

Comment: Yes, it should be 1,1

Comment: If it feels slow that's because it can assume nothing about your list that would enable smarter behavior. Does the list have some guaranteed property that can help? If not, there's nothing better.

Comment: You are picking index or value? because in the above list 3 is there at 10th position also.

Comment: @Naveen I'm picking the value. The 3 in the 10th position should not be taken into account

Comment: how its possible? If so how you will pick the 10th 3?

Comment: I will not use the 10th 3 because when I go through the list to the right I get the value 4. And then the condition about similar values is not met anymore.

Comment: That is correct, But i am asking about your picking value. If you want to pick/select 10th 3, then how you will pick it?

Comment: The user can select the index in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible but not elegant solution:

```
List<int> myList = new List<int> { 8, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 3, 8 };

        var index = 5;

        var element = myList.ElementAt(index);
        int firstIndex=index, lastIndex=index;

        int i, j;
        bool control1 = true, control2 = true;
        for (i = index, j = index; ; i--, j++)
        {
            if (control1 && i >= 0 && myList[i] == element)
            {
                firstIndex = i;
            }
            else
            {
                control1 = false;
            }

            if (control2 && j < myList.Count && myList[j] == element)
            {
                lastIndex = j;
            }
            else
            {
                control2 = false;
            }

            if (!control1 && !control2) break;
            if (i < 0 && j >= myList.Count) break;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(firstIndex);
        Console.WriteLine(lastIndex);
```

Outputs:

```
// index = 5

   firstIndex = 2, lastIndex = 7

// index = 1

    firstIndex = 1, lastIndex = 1

// index = 8

    firstIndex = 8, lastIndex = 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about large lists, two threads doing your approach might be useful. You'd need a function like

```
int getSimilarIndex(IReadOnlyList<int> list, int startIndex, bool forward) {
    int index = startIndex;
    int startElement = list[startIndex];
    while (forward ? (index < list.Count) : (index >= 0) ) {    
        if (!isSimilar(list[index], startElemen))
            break;
        if (forward)
            ++index;
        else
            ++index;
    }
    return index;
}
```

which returns the fist/last index of similar entries. Now you could assign two versions of that function to ThreadPool-Threads:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem( (WaitCallback) delegate {
    this.minSimilarIndex = getSimilarIndex(list, startIndex, false);
    });
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem( (WaitCallback) delegate {
    this.maxSimilarIndex = getSimilarIndex(list, startIndex, true);
    });
```

You also might want to add events to the function in order to signal that the job is completed.

Comment: "Might want" is kind of an understatement, like saying you might want to use sunscreen on the beach.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution:

```
var myList = new List<int>() { 8, 5, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 3, 8 };
int givenIndex = 11;
int givenValue = myList[givenIndex];
bool firstFound = false, lastFound = false;
int firstIndex = givenIndex, lastIndex = givenIndex;
int index = 1;
int length = myList.Count;

while (!(firstFound && lastFound))
{
    if (!lastFound && (givenIndex + index >= length || myList[givenIndex + index] != givenValue))
    {
        lastFound = true;
        lastIndex = givenIndex + index - 1;
    }
    if (!firstFound && (givenIndex - index <= 0 || myList[givenIndex - index] != givenValue))
    {
        firstFound = true;
        firstIndex = givenIndex - index + 1;
    }

    index++;
}

Console.WriteLine("The first index is {0} and the last index is {1}.", firstIndex, lastIndex);
}
```